# Discussion about publication bias in academia on another site

Tags: discussion

There was an interesting discussion at the stats Cross Validated site about [(mis)use of statistics in academic papers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/92213/5739). I think the audience of Academia will benefit from it, but I am not sure what the best way is to link to that discussion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you've done here is probably the best way. The Stack Exchange sites are set up to answer questions, not really to share cool stuff across sites.

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Meta is a good place to bring attention to interesting things. You could also link the discussion in chat. If you have an answerable question about the discussion that is relevant to academics you could ask that question on the main site.